# How to call AWS Glue Job with certain amount of DPU's by boto3 python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, boto3, aws-glue

I had been trying to call a Glue job successfully using a boto3 python script by API.

But I'm unable to call the Glue Job with more DPU's than it's current allocation.

Does anyone know if there is a documentation which helps to increase DPU limit through a python script from boto3 API ?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (even if the default DPU allocation is lower / higher):

```
glue_client = boto3.client(
    'glue', region_name='your-region'
)


 glue_client.start_job_run(
            JobName='your_job_name',
            NumberOfWorkers=10)
```